# While Uploading APK in beta version error occurs that Upload failed

Tags: android, firebase

I have uploaded application few times with my app keystore, so i know the password i have is correct, but now when I am uploading my application in beta testing but the error occurs:

**You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You** **must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:**

**[ SHA1: xxxxxxxxxxxxx ]**

**and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:**

**[ SHA1: xxxxxxxxxxxx ]**

Any proceeding will be helpful, as it happens to one more application.

I have added firebase in both projects, so is there any possibility that this issue can occur because of it.?

Comment: Release key you are using to sign your project should be same.

Comment: i think you have made a new .jks file that's why its happening you have to use your old one .jks file.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta, i have pull the code from github, so i haven't create new .jks file.

Comment: what procedure have you done? can you tell me in detail and stepwise?

Comment: @ParasWatts your mean keystore.?

Comment: Yes. The keystore file

Comment: @AbhinavGupta, i simply generate signed apk using existing key store and provide the path of the keystore, after filling alias name and password, i checked V1 and V2 and finish it. i drop the created apk in beta testing.

Comment: @ParasWatts i am using existing keystore file.

Comment: @VinayGupta can you share your github project link

Comment: @AbhinavGupta, actually it is closed.